# Harry Potter fan-fic where Harry was abused and rescued by the Order

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember a few things that happened in this fan-fic. Harry was abused. He was rescued by the order.

1. Order gets worried when Harry stops writing
2. Harry gets in trouble or something. He was locked in his room. Petunia brought him food and water, and later a big glass of water
3. Vernon gets mad again and beats Harry to a pulp.
4. Part of the order goes to rescue Harry (I specifically remember Tonks and someone else. Possibly Harry?)
5. This is disgusting, but I remember Harry barfed on himself and his bed, then Tonks put her knees in it?
6. He was transported to Hogwarts
7. Snape had to make all of the potions
8. St. Mungo's people helped Harry who was in “critical condition”
9. Harry was floating above his bed.
10. There were alarm orbs or something
11. Snape and Dumbledore both glowed when Harry coded. (According to Harry) Snape glowed green and Dumbledore glowed purple. They both also glowed unrecognizable colors.
12. Harry wasn’t supposed to feel anything but his head. He coded when he had a blood clot because he felt pain in his neck? Poppy was trying to fix it.

That’s really all I remember. I think it may have started with a “k” but I’m not sure.

Comment: what time period was this based in? That is, did it mention which year Harry was in in the story?

Comment: Going by the title and some of the points, it could be canon.

Comment: Do you remember what site you read this on and when?